# while installing ubuntu i deleted the windows os but the remaining drive is still there how to include them with ubuntu

Tags: xubuntu

While installing Ubuntu I deleted the windows operating system but the remaining drive is still there how to include them with Ubuntu.

In my case I selected the last option something else and the I deleted the partition on which windows was installed and some small partition. I am not deleted the other partitions in which my data resides.

experts can you please help me that how can I include those partition. I think they still exists in hard disk , because I currently I am able to see on 130 GB, and my total hard disk size is 320 GB.

Comment: In Ubuntu open Software Center. Inside search for Gparted, and click install to install it (if not already installed). Next Open Gparted and take a screenshot of Gparted. You can use the Alt+Print Screen keys together to take a screenshot. Upload the scheenshot image in http://imgur.com/ . Finally, [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/926544/edit) your question and add a link to your uploaded image of the screenshot in imagur.

Comment: Please also take a screenshot of your Files program and upload and link in your question. In particular, you should see the "remaining drive" on the left panel of your Files program. In Ubuntu the Files program is also known as Nautilus.

Answer (score 0):

If you deleted the partitions, then the space is unallocated.
tell ubuntu to use the free space when you install.

the small partition you deleted was probably the EFI partition so be sure that the installer boots up efi mode not bios mode.

Comment: thanks every one for your support , but unfortunately i lost my data. But still not worries , any thing acceptable to learn Linux. :-)\]